# A program that sends me a message to my smartphone whenever someone start my computer?

Tags: windows, email

Does there exist a  program that sends me a message (email accepted) to my smartphone whenever someone start my computer?

- I need it because I want to know when someone uses my computer when I'm not there (the computer is considered as always online).
- I want the application to run  on Windows.

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/50) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Comment: @aman207 Edited, do I need to add more in there?

Comment: @3azi no worries. I will work on it now. I've always wanted something like this, too. Now I have a reason to make it. What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: This question is still lacking lots of information: communcation protocols, what sort of “smartphones” including versions, etc. – unless you just want a generic eMail, which is trivial…

Answer (score 1):

I use [KakaoTalk](http://www.kakao.com/talk/en) (free with over 100 million users) for this. I installed the Windows client for KakaoTalk, each time Windows starts it sends a message to my KakaoTalk client on Android (works on iPhone and Windows Phone too):

[image: KakaoTalk]
<sup>*KakaoTalk screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

The main issue is that it only works for one computer since you cannot be logged on several computers at once.

Comment: This app doesn't work for me

Comment: Can you expand?

Comment: @3azi - it seems to fit the requirements in your question. Maybe you should expand the question with whatever it is that this program doesn't have and that you do want to have

Comment: What if the PC user closes KakaoTalk as soon as it starts loading?